# Formatting datetime in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with number of different dates as index:

```
2005-01-02 
2005-01-03 
2005-01-04 
2005-01-04 
... 
2014-12-30 
2014-12-31
```

and i want to format them as `MM-DD` without changing the type to string. Can someone help me with that? And second question: If I do that, can I still use `dt.dayofyear`?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Simple way

```
df.index.str[5:]
```

More common way

```
df.index.strftime('%m-%d')
```

Comment: It works of course but object type changes from datetime64 to string and I don't want that